# How do I generate an array type in a Roslyn code generator?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-generation, roslyn

I want to generate a method with a return type of `Foo[]`. My code looks roughly like this (with `using static SyntaxFactory`):

```
var methodDecl = MethodDeclaration(
    returnType: ArrayType(IdentifierName("Foo")),
    identifier: Identifier("Bar"),
    parameterList: ParameterList(),
    body: Block(ReturnStatement(LiteralExpression(SyntaxKind.NullLiteralExpression))),
    // ...
);
```

When I execute my refactoring in the debug Visual Studio window, it doesn't generate the `[]` part of the `Foo[]` type:

```
Foo Bar()
{
    return null;
}
```

How do I make it generate an actual `Foo[]` type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `[]` part of the array type is called a *rank specifier*. The rank specifier describes the size and dimensionality of the array, à la `int[10,3][12]`.

The `ArrayType` factory method creates an `ArrayTypeSyntax` with no `RankSpecifiers` at all. To generate the commonly-used `Foo[]` syntax, you need to give it a single empty rank specifier.

```
ArrayType(IdentifierName("Foo"), SingletonList(ArrayRankSpecifier()))
```

Seems like a bit of a silly default to me, since 1D arrays are by far the most common. As far as I know this isn't documented anywhere.